# how to calculate number of element in nested document with mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

There is one MongoDB document:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54afa7258461d95d458b45e2"),
    "event_time" : ISODate("2015-01-09T11:02:13.000Z"),
    "event_type" : "s",
    "objects" : {
        "obj_id" : [ 
            3019, 
            2868, 
            2496, 
            2981, 
            2970, 
            2952
        ]
    }
}
```

How to calculate number of items in sub document objects.obj_id with MapReduce, with total per event_type?
Aggregation framework is unusable due to large amounts of data and result is bigger than 16MB.

Any idea?

Comment: The number of items in _each_ document ? Or the total for _all_ documents ?

Comment: total per event_type

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of items for all sub documents `objects.obj_id` of a given `item_type`, you only have to emit the array length in the [*map* step](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-map-function). And associate that value with your `event_type`. The [*reduce* step](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) is a simple sum:

```
map = function() {
  emit(this.event_type, this.objects.obj_id.length)
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
   return values.reduce(function(a,b) { return a+b})
}
```

Given you sample data, this will produce:

```
> db.test.mapReduce(map,dummy, {out:{inline:1}}).results
[ { "_id" : "s", "value" : 6 } } ]
```

Comment: I try. this works! I make mistake and try calculate lenghts in reduce func :(
Thx

Comment: @sasa Usually, all the _hard_ work is done in the _map_ step. The only purpose of the _reduce_ step is to aggregate the values computed in the map step. But I agree that map-reduce can be confusing sometimes  ;)